# Avoiding an image hover content from resizing on windows resize

Tags: html, css, image

hello guys I am designing a website which consist of an image and a hover effect which fades out a text. it is pretty working fine but it became a mess when i resized the browser window, the image is still positioned but the hover content resizes i just want it to be the same size with the image on resize.
 Any way out of this mess, any answer is appreciated thanks.

```css
figure {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure:hover img {
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  width: 90% !important;
  height: 95%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  color: #000;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.styleme {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: playball;
  margin-top: 36%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="macbookair11_lifestyle_20.jpg" />
        <figcaption>
          <div class="styleme">
            <p>This is the Apple macbook and it is pro <i class="fa fa-apple"></i> justclick to purchase</p>
            <p>Proccessor: works at 3.14Ghz</p>
            <p>Internal Ram: It has a Ram of 8GB <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is `figcaption` absolutely positioned? why not just have it flow normally on the page?

Comment: I have just tried it now, but the hover content leaves the image entirely. thanks for you concern .but if there is still any answer to it i appreciate thanks @Michael Coker

Comment: @FillipoSniper try my answer

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BZvoVj

Comment: i have also tried it but it is still not working out i have created a fiddle to demonstrate to you what i am talking about looks like at (https://jsfiddle.net/h5x82ao3/6/) @Michael Coker

Comment: Where exactly do you want the caption to appear?

Comment: i just want it to appear on the image but the problem i am having is that when i resize the browser window the caption also changes in position. So i just want it to be relative with the image as it resizies. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, your image must be very large if you want it to fill most of the page. I have used a small image and sized appropriately for demo purposes.

The key difference I made was to use `display:block` and `position:relative`.

It's good to minimise the use of absolute positioning where possible. (That's why I adjusted the top and left to margin-top and margin-left)

Adjust the numbers in the css as you see appropriate

Hope this helps

```css
figure {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure:hover img {
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

figure figcaption {
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 400px !important;
  height: 450px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  color: #000;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.styleme {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: playball;
  margin-top: 10%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSs87UCUOVgNUoz7-AlLppXgeDyC1DnITzZjk6xMJN4P94oMps1" />
        <figcaption>
          <div class="styleme">
            <p>This is the Apple macbook and it is pro <i class="fa fa-apple"></i> justclick to purchase</p>
            <p>Proccessor: works at 3.14Ghz</p>
            <p>Internal Ram: It has a Ram of 8GB <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  (snippet 2 with larger image)

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
.thumbnail{
   background: #fff;
}
figure img{
  width:90%!important;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure:hover img {
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

figure figcaption{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  color: #000;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.styleme {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: playball;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width:90%;
  height:10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">

      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmGtZotDeGTAe1MOM1QZ-g6HfFnBCE3ASqsoUcSmfcMgHLPSOMyw" />
        <figcaption>
          <div class="styleme">
            <p>This is the Apple macbook and it is pro <i class="fa fa-apple"></i> just click to purchase</p>
            <p>Processor: works at 3.14Ghz</p>
            <p>Internal Ram: It has a Ram of 8GB <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/4yqLeey9/

Comment: (better viewed if you view the snippet full-screen)

Comment: I tried it still but the hover content still proves to be adamant to it i still face the same problem. thanks for your concern @Rachel Gallen.

Comment: Hello don't feel like I am disturbing but try to change the background it still resizes. and the hover content I mean is like an overlay on the image (absolute).So it is fading in over the image on hover. Thanks @Rachel Gallen

Comment: @FillipoSniper here's some fiddles that may/may not be useful https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f0fsLd2h/ , https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/1/ (created by someone else, don't know who but the effect is nice), and http://fiddle.jshell.net/RachGal/zgrbuqow/  I hope these are of some help.

Comment: I have got it at this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/1/ ) I only checked the first one. thanks for solving the problem for me. and promising not to disturb again lol :) @Rachel Gallen

Comment: @FillipoSniper you mean you resolved the problem? HURRAH!